# ESLint - no-unused-expressions in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring, eslint

Getting a ESLint error when copiling with babel:

- Line 28:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
- Line 29:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Any idea how to get rid of these whilst making my timer still work as intended? Or have you got a better way of me doing my timer?

```
class RequestTimer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            seconds: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            hours: 0
        }

        this.getTime = this.getTime.bind(this);
    }    

    getTime() {
        let second = this.state.seconds
        let minute = this.state.minutes;
        let hour = this.state.hours; 

        this.state.seconds % 59 === 0 && this.state.seconds !== 0 ? minute += 1:null;
        this.state.minutes % 59 === 0 && this.state.seconds % 59 === 0 && this.state.minutes !== 0 ? (hour += 1, minute = 0):null;

        this.setState({
            seconds: second +=1,
            minutes: minute,
            hours: hour
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(this.getTime, 1000)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TimerContainer>
                <h2>Last Request:</h2>
                <p>{this.state.hours}h {this.state.minutes}m {this.state.seconds % 60}s</p>                
            </TimerContainer>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use a proper `if` statement:

```
getTime() {
    let second = this.state.seconds
    let minute = this.state.minutes;
    let hour = this.state.hours; 

    if (this.state.seconds % 59 === 0 && this.state.seconds !== 0) {
        minute += 1;
    }
    if (this.state.minutes % 59 === 0 && this.state.seconds % 59 === 0 && this.state.minutes !== 0) {
        hour += 1;
        minute = 0;
    }

    this.setState({
        seconds: second +=1,
        minutes: minute,
        hours: hour
    });
}
```

Don't use the ternary operator if you don't want to do anything with the result value. And especially you should not use it when you have no `else` case or when you have to use the comma operator to do multiple things.

Answer (score 6):

There are couple of solution.

1.) Just Disable the rule for the entire file using eslint-disable at the **top of the file.**

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
```

2.) You should write below code at the end off all lines(28,29) so It's disabled.

```
/* eslint-disable-line */
```

Comment: Your answer is not wrong but you took wrong approach. Instead of disabling rule. You should go to refactor the code.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively modify the ternary operation to have a left hand side expression. Change this:

`this.state.seconds % 59 === 0 && this.state.seconds !== 0 ? minute += 1:null;`

To this:

`minute = this.state.seconds % 59 === 0 && this.state.seconds !== 0 ? minute + 1:null;`