# Error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions. How to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, compiler-errors

I'm actually trying to connect my db to a react app and it keeps showing me this errors in three different places that i highlight with ">>" below

```
 handleDBReponse(response) {
    const appointments = response;
    const today = moment().startOf("day"); //start of today 12 am
    const initialSchedule = {};
    initialSchedule[today.format("YYYY-DD-MM")] = true;
    const schedule = !appointments.length
      ? initialSchedule
      : appointments.reduce((currentSchedule, appointment) => {
          const { slot_date, slot_time } = appointment;
          const dateString = moment(slot_date, "YYYY-DD-MM").format(
            "YYYY-DD-MM"
          );
>>          !currentSchedule[slot_date]
            ? (currentSchedule[dateString] = Array(8).fill(false))
            : null;
>>          Array.isArray(currentSchedule[dateString])
            ? (currentSchedule[dateString][slot_time] = true)
            : null;
          return currentSchedule;
        }, initialSchedule);
    for (let day in schedule) {
      let slots = schedule[day];
>>      slots.length
        ? slots.every(slot => slot === true) ? (schedule[day] = true) : null
        : null;
    }
    this.setState({
      schedule: schedule
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESLint - no-unused-expressions in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274829/eslint-no-unused-expressions-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all three cases you're doing something like

```
condition ? something = somethingElse : null
```

So if condition is falsy, it evaluates to `false null`, which doesn't really make sense.  I think it would be easier to read and get rid of the warnings if you did something like

```
if (condition) something = somethingElse
```

So in the first case

```
!currentSchedule[slot_date]
  ? (currentSchedule[dateString] = Array(8).fill(false))
  : null;
```

should be

```
if (!currentSchedule[slot_date]) {
  (currentSchedule[dateString] = Array(8).fill(false));
}
```