# no-unused-expressions in React with conditionals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, babeljs

I have a form that needs to validate a const first, if true, open the modal, if false, submit the form.

I did this, this works but I'm getting the error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
> @babel/no-unused-expressions

```
modalOpen = () => this.setState({ showModal: true });

const validateType = !someAttribute && hasChange;

const submit = () => {
    validateType ? this.modalOpen() : handleSubmit();
};

// Do I need to have this submit here too?
<Form className={cn} onSubmit={isReadOnly ? () => {} : handleSubmit} readOnly={isReadOnly}>

    <Button
        type="button"
        onClick={submit}
    />
</Form>
```

The error occurs on this line here:

```
validateType ? this.modalOpen() : handleSubmit();
```

I looked at the documentation and I really don't understand why this error is happening.

If anyone can help me understand I would be very grateful.

Comment: Why are you using .this for modalOpen and not handleSubmit? Show the whole code so we can see where these functions are declared and what kind of component it's in

Comment: @msmoore I need to open a validation modal before submitting in case it turns to true

Comment: As the code isn't separated by functions, modalOpen() function doesn't have to be called with this?

Comment: @jacobkim How? I don't think I understand, sorry

Comment: Try onSubmit={isReadOnly ? () => {} : () => handleSubmit()}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESLint - no-unused-expressions in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274829/eslint-no-unused-expressions-in-reactjs)

Comment: might be an eslint permission issue: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions

Comment: @gmcode I just asked and the example code doesn't make me understand. Hope you find your answer. I always forget but functions should end with `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 - replace ternary with `if/else`:

```
const submit = () => {
  if(validateType) this.modalOpen(); 
  else handleSubmit();
};
```

Option 2 - find the rule in your `.eslint` file, and change to rule to [allow ternary](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions#allowternary) expressions:

```
no-unused-expressions: ["error", { "allowTernary": true }]
```

Option 3 - ignore eslint for this line:

```
const submit = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
  validateType ? this.modalOpen() : handleSubmit();
};
```